# How to install Sogou input method on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, dependencies, chinese, fcitx

I downloaded the 64-bit package for the Sogou input method from here https://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/

When I try to install it there are dependency errors on Ubuntu 20.04

```
Note, selecting 'sogoupinyin' instead of './sogoupinyin_2.3.1.0112_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sogoupinyin : Depends: fcitx-frontend-qt4 but it is not installable
               Depends: libqtwebkit4 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What solution is there to get Sogou input up and running on Ubuntu 20.04?

Thanks

Comment: Both of those packages are in the Universe repository. [Enable it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository). Then run `sudo apt update` (becasue your sources changed). Then try installing again.

Comment: @user535733 I enabled it and it still cannot find the packages, I searched in synaptic and cannot find the missing dependencies

Comment: Whoops. You are correct! Both those packages were dropped from Ubuntu after 19.10. Be sure to let the sogoupinyin developers know that those dependencies need to be changed in their package. Are you willing to install 18.04 to run the package? Or you can try manually downloading the 19.10 packages from http://packages.ubuntu.com and installing them.

Comment: That will be quite a few packages to download, I may see if I can get them to update the package

Comment: Qt4 is EOL and was removed from Ubuntu in 2019 (2015 upstream was announced EOL though Debian & Ubuntu supported it until 15-Mar-2019) ; (for more details refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295). The package if maintained should have been ported to Qt5 (introduced 19-Dec-2012) before now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I modified the .deb file, i.e. dropped those two dependencies. The result can be downloaded here:

[https://people.ubuntu.com/~gunnarhj/sogoupinyin_2.3.1.0112+noQt4Deps_amd64.deb](https://people.ubuntu.com/%7Egunnarhj/sogoupinyin_2.3.1.0112+noQt4Deps_amd64.deb)

Then navigate to the Downloads folder and do:

```
sudo apt install ./sogoupinyin_2.3.1.0112+noQt4Deps_amd64.deb
```

But this should really not be needed. The sogoupinyin maintainers should port that package to Qt5 or at least drop the Qt4 runtime dependencies.

*Edit:*

This has been fixed in the latest version; see answer posted by [handsome_feng](https://askubuntu.com/users/680705/handsome-feng).

Answer (score 4):

The new version of sogou ( v2.3.2.07) already fixed the dependency issue, see: https://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/changelog.php